# Excel Count from IF Array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables containing data on names with a pass/fail variable. I am trying to count how many people originally failed but then passed later on.

| Name | Passed |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | Passed |
| John | Failed |
| Billy | Failed |

| Name | Passed |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | Passed |
| John | Passed |
| Billy | Failed |

I originally did this by creating a third table with an IF array that put out the names of the people who failed. I then counted the amount of "TRUE"s.

For Name:

```
=IFERROR(IFS(Table13[Passed]="FAILED", Table13[Name]), "")
```

For Passed Later:

```
=IF(XLOOKUP(VALUETOTEXT(A2),Table1[Name],Table1[Passed])="Passed",TRUE,FALSE)
```

| Name | Passed Originally | Passed Later |
| --- | --- | --- |
| #N/A | #N/A | #N/A |
| John | Failed | TRUE |
| Billy | Failed | FALSE |

And finally got the count by

```
=COUNTIF(Table3[Passed Later], "=TRUE")
```

I was able to skip the name column and got the Passed Later column directly by combining the first two formulas into

```
=IF(XLOOKUP(IFS(Table13[Passed]="Failed", Table13[Name]),Table1[Name],Table1[Passed])="Passed",TRUE,FALSE)
```

Now I am stuck at combining the COUNTIF Function. I do not know how I can implement this all into one function, if that is possible. Any advise?
I think my main problem is the output of the Passed Later column is not numbers, but strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Two Filters and check if the first is found in the second with IsNumber(Match())

```
=LET(
    fst,FILTER(Table13[Name],Table13[Passed]="Failed"),
    scd,FILTER(Table1[Name],Table1[Passed]= "Passed"), 
    SUM(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(fst,scd,0))))
```

[image]

---

If you want the name of who failed then passed add another Filter:

```
=LET(
    fst,FILTER(Table13[Name],Table13[Passed]="Failed"),
    scd,FILTER(Table1[Name],Table1[Passed]= "Passed"),
    FILTER(fst,ISNUMBER(MATCH(fst,scd,0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this works, gave me the same number as my own answer and as my original messy way. It's a lot cleaner and simpler than my own, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Would the following work:

[image]

Formula in `G1`:

```
=FILTER(A2:A5,COUNTIFS(A2:A5,A2:A5,B2:B5,"Failed")*COUNTIFS(D2:D5,A2:A5,E2:E5,"Passed"))
```

---

Or, if you want a count:

[image]

Formula in `H1`:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A5,FILTER(D2:D5,E2:E5="Passed"),B2:B5,"Failed"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the correct answer, but it works.

After typing:

> I think my main problem is the output of the Passed Later column is not numbers, but strings.

I was able to figure it out. I just needed to give a number output on the last if statement for "Passed" and a string for "Failed". Here is my final formula, at least the solution I came to.

```
=COUNT(IF(XLOOKUP(IFS(Table13[Passed]<>1, Table13[Name]),Table1[Name],Table1[Passed])=1,1,""))
```

Figured I would leave this up to help others.